# Smart client applications with .NET 3.5

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, clickonce

I have used smart client type apps which are enbedded in html way back in .net 1.1.  I now have .net 3.5 and wanted to know if there is a new way of creating embedded smart client type applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you tagged this question as "ClickOnce" but that is your solution.

Clickonce was introduced by Microsoft with the 2.0 .Net framework.

Here are  a few articles to get you started.

- [Microsoft HOWTO on publishing
  applications via ClickOnce.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey.aspx)
- [The ClickOnce Application
  Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k390a.aspx)-- This is information
  regarding how and where your
  application will be stored on your
  user's PC.
- [Manual Deployment of a ClickOnce
  Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx) (e.g. not through
  Visual Studio.)

Those articles should get you started and there are certainly many others.  If you have any further questions, please post them within the ClickOnce tag.